# I'm trying to connect to oracledb from node facing the below error

Tags: node.js, node-oracledb

> Error:
>   \?\D:\E142\NodeWorkspace\Database\node_modules\oracledb\build\Release\oracledb.node
>   is not a 
>   application\?\D:\E142\NodeWorkspace\Database\node_modules\oracledb\build\Release\oracledb.node
>   at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:653:18)  at Module.load
>   (module.js:545:32)  at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)  at
>   Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)  at Module.require
>   (module.js:568:17)  at require (internal/module.js:11:18)  at
>   Object.
>   (D:\E142\NodeWorkspace\Database\node_modules\oracledb\lib\oracledb.js:35:19)
>   at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)  at
>   Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)  at Module.load
>   (module.js:545:32)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
Open an elevated CMD prompt (run as Administrator).
navigate to your app folder
npm install --global npm
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
npm install instantclient
set PATH=%cd%\instantclient;%PATH%
set OCI_LIB_DIR=%cd%\instantclient\sdk\lib\msvc
set OCI_INC_DIR=%cd%\instantclient\sdk\include
npm install oracledb
```